# Pytest report summary to display error information

Tags: python, pytest

I am relatively new to pytest hooks and plugins and I am unable to figure out how to get my pytest code to give me test execution summary with reason of failure.

Consider the code:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def test_compare12():
        f1 = Foo(1)
        f2 = Foo(2)
        assert f1 == f2, "F2 does not match F1"

    def test_compare34():
        f3 = Foo(3)
        f4 = Foo(4)
        assert f3 == f4, "F4 does not match F3"
```

When I run the pytest script with -v option, it gives me the following result on the console:

```
========================= test session starts=================================
platform darwin -- Python 2.7.5 -- py-1.4.26 -- pytest-2.7.0 --    /Users/nehau/src/QA/bin/python
rootdir: /Users/nehau/src/QA/test, inifile: 
plugins: capturelog
collected 2 items 

test_foocompare.py::test_compare12 FAILED
test_foocompare.py::test_compare34 FAILED

================================ FAILURES ===============================
_______________________________ test_compare12 _________________________

def test_compare12():
    f1 = Foo(1)
    f2 = Foo(2)
>       assert f1 == f2, "F2 does not match F1"
E       AssertionError: F2 does not match F1
E       assert <test.test_foocompare.Foo instance at 0x107640368> == <test.test_foocompare.Foo instance at 0x107640488>

test_foocompare.py:11: AssertionError
_____________________________ test_compare34______________________________

def test_compare34():
    f3 = Foo(3)
    f4 = Foo(4)
>       assert f3 == f4, "F4 does not match F3"
E       AssertionError: F4 does not match F3
E       assert <test.test_foocompare.Foo instance at 0x107640248> == <test.test_foocompare.Foo instance at 0x10761fe60>

test_foocompare.py:16: AssertionError

=============================== 2 failed in 0.01 seconds ==========================
```

I am running close to 2000 test cases, so it would be really helpful if I could have pytest display output in the following format:

```
::
test_foocompare.py::test_compare12 FAILED AssertionError:F2 does not match F1
test_foocompare.py::test_compare34 FAILED AssertionError:F2 does not match F1
::
```

I have looked at pytest_runtest_makereport plugin but can't seem to get it working. Anyone has any other ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 30):

Try the -tb flag:

`pytest --tb=line`

This gives one line of output per test.
See [the docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#modifying-python-traceback-printing).

Comment: can this also show the line number of the failed asset() check?

Answer (score 15):

Also try `pytest -v --tb=no` to show all pass/fail results.

Answer (score 12):

Try `-rA` option of `pytest`. It will provide a summary at the end of the logs  that show all (failures, skips, etc. and passed).

See https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#detailed-summary-report

Comment: I did try -rf option but that just gives me the failed test cases without any insight into the reason of failure.